# Can anyone help me understand how to center my html table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a set of tables that look like this

[image]

When I put info in them however they end up looking all over the place like this

[image: https://gyazo.com/fbf881a10c82c14b93a0c9773c9f511d]

the current formatting that I have for my tables is just trying to get them centered by using relative positioning and pixels from top and left like this

```
   #damagetablemario {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:700px;
    left:80px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
   #damagetablemario2 {
   display:none;
   position:relative;
   top:400px;
   left:110px;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
   #damagetablemario3 {
   display:none;
   position:relative;
   top:450px;
   left:540px;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   margin-bottom:200px;
}




    <table id = "damagetablemario">
      <tr>
      <th>Neutral</th>
      <th>Forward  Tilt</th>
      <th>Up Tilt</th>
      <th>Down-Tilt</th>
      <th>Forward-Smash</th>
      <th>Up-Smash</th>
      <th>Down-Smash</th>
      <th>Neutral-Air</th>
      <th>Forward-Air</th>
      <th>Back-Air</th>
      <th>Up-Air</th>
      <th>Down-Air</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class = "Neutral">2.2% (punch)<br>1.7% (punch)<br> 4% (kick)</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Tilt">7%</td>
      <td class = "Up-Tilt">5.5%</td>
      <td class = "Down-Tilt">5% (foot) <br> 7% (body)</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Smash">17.8% (fire)<br> 14.7% (arm)</td>
      <td class = "Up-Smash">14%</td>
      <td class = "Down-Smash">10% (front)<br> 12% (back)</td>
      <td class = "Neutral-Air">8% (clean)<br> 5% (late)</td>
      <td class = "Forward-Air">12% (early)<br> 14% (clean)<br> 10%(late)</td>
      <td class = "Back-Air">10.5% (clean)<br> 7% (late)</td>
      <td class = "Up-Air">7%</td>
      <td class = "Down-Air">1.4% (1-5 hits) <br>
         5.5% (hit  6) <br>
         2% (landing)
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I can't figure out how to make them centered any other way. Any one have any ways to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/yt09175x/3/

Comment: I will be great if you share your code with JSFiddle or anything else.

Comment: If you can post your HTML code, it would be a great help to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your left margins to specific numbers, so your tables are starting at those points and adding the data is skewing the size of your table.

You can fix this multiple ways, but here's my recommendation:

```css
table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
  }
```

```html
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
    <td>Fourth</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <table class="center">
   <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>Five</td>
    <td>Six</td>
    <td>Seven</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <table class="center">
   <tr>
    <td>AAAA</td>
    <td>BBBB</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yt09175x/3/ so when I put the center like I did in this snippet the tables just go all over my screen as opposed to being centered.